# Proof of the second symmetric derivative using L'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

So, I need to prove the symmetric second derivative

$f''(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)-2f(x_0)}{h^{2}}.$

And I want to prove it using L'Hôpital:

$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)-2f(x_0)}{h^{2}} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0-h)}{2h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f''(x_0+h)+f''(x_0-h)}{2} = f''(x_0).$

I do know how to use L'Hôpital's Rule, but I have a few questions like..... where is the $-2f(x_0)$ term that just vanished? why is the middle sign changing from + to - and then to + again? I guess all I need is to see a few more steps before getting to the final result.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable of the limit is $h$, we're interested in $\frac{d}{dh}$. Notice that $x_0$ is *constant* with respect to $h$ (so $f(x_0)$ is also constante W.R.T. $h$), so taking the $h$-derivative of $f(x_0)$ is the same as taking the derivative of $3$ or $\pi$ since it's just a constant. With this in mind, we see that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dh}\left[f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)-2f(x_0)\right] &= f'(x_0 + h) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dh} \left(x_0+h\right)}_{+1} +  f'(x_0 -h) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dh} \left(x_0\mathbin{\color{red}{-}} h\right)}_{\mathbin{\color{red}{-}}1}  -  \frac{d}{dh}\underbrace{2f(x_0)}_{\color{Blue}{\text{Constant}}}\\
& = f'(x_0 + h) \mathbin{\color{red}{-}} f'(x_0 - h) -\color{Blue}{ 0}
\end{align*}
where we used the chain rule on the first $2$ terms, and recalled that the derivative of a constant is $0$ for the last term.

For the last equality we essentially do the same thing:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dh} \left[f'(x_0 + h) - f'(x_0 -h)\right] & = f''(x_0 + h) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dh} \left(x_0+h\right)}_{+1} - f''(x_0 -h) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dh} \left(x_0\mathbin{\color{red}{-}} h\right)}_{\mathbin{\color{red}{-}}1}\\
& = f''(x_0 + h) - \left[\color{red}{-}f''(x_0 + h) \right]\\
& = f''(x_0 + h)  + f''(x_0 + h)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that with L'hopital you're taking the derivative with respect to the variable of the limit (namely $h$). So $f(x_0)$ is constant, and the signs are switching because of the chain rule.